# jQuery toggle two elements with one click

Tags: css, jquery

I've got a little problem, which is onclick function fails to make simultaneously two different changes to html document. What's needed is - click on link should toggle "active" class of parent element and toggle visibility of respective hidden div. What I've got is changes are made alternately with each successive click (I provided jsfiddle link below).
Worked fine until I added closest() (or parent()) function. I have no idea what's going on. Would appreciate some help.

Here is html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="argle"><a href="#">Argle</a>
</div>
<div class="bargle"><a href="#">Bargle</a>
</div>
<div class="shmargle"><a href="#">Schmargle</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="windows">
<div class="w-argle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,</div>
<div class="w-bargle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed     diam    nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam er</div>
<div class="w-shmargle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,.</div>
</div>
```

Here is js:

```
$(function () {
$('#wrapper a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var parentElement = $(this).closest('div');
    var targetElement = $('.w-' + parentElement.attr('class'));
    parentElement.toggleClass('active');
    targetElement.toggle();
});

});
```

Online here: http://jsfiddle.net/alalpgrlv/ycJk4/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add "active" class to the  element, and then you use it as a part of selector in targetElement so targetElement will be i.e.: $('.w-argle active') which not exists.
Try this.

```
cls = (parentElement.attr('class').split(" "))[0];
var targetElement = $('.w-' + cls);
```

Comment: Thank you, now it seems so obvious, how I didn't come to this myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Working example : <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ycJk4/5/)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $('#wrapper a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var parentElement = $(this).closest('div');
        var targetElement = $('.w-' + parentElement.attr('class'));

        //Hide all other div
        $('[class^=w-]').not(targetElement).hide();

        //Remove active class
        $('#wrapper').find('div').not(parentElement).removeClass('active');

        //Toggle clicked link
        parentElement.toggleClass('active');        
        targetElement.toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".argle").click(function(){
$("#windows").find('.w-argle').slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ablealias/zCFff/1/

Answer (score 0):

You want like this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/ycJk4/6/

```
$(function () {
    $('#wrapper a').click(function (event) {
        $('#windows div').slideUp();
        $('#windows .w-'+$(this).parent('div').attr('class')).slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem appears, because you add the class active to the parentElement. ( that means the second time, you are searching for an in-existent element ).

You can try to get only the first class

```
parentElement.attr('class').split(" "))[0];
```

or you can simple add the targetElement class using HTML5 data on the element.

I modified your example, here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/ycJk4/7/